# Adding Java home not working on windows ZSH

Tags: java, windows, oh-my-zsh

I have java installed and set up properly and works fine with the normal Windows Powershell. However, I'm trying to make java work with the ZSH terminal and I cannot get it to work.

My JAVA_HOME (in powershell) is set to this path:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

Im trying to add this line to my .zshrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/mnt/c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk-15.0.2`
```

but when i do source .zshrc it says permission denied to that file. Running sudo chmod doesnt seem to help either. Am i doing something wrong or missing some other line to add? Most tutorials for ZSH is on a Mac OS so i dont know if it differs being that im in windows...

Comment: A Linux environment shouldn't be using a Windows Java installation path, anyway.

Comment: Oh, so how should I go about having a different installation path for the linux environment itself?

Comment: The path doesn't really matter. You should use something like `apt install openjdk`, for example, assuming you are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backticks are trying to "execute" that folder as a shell command.

Double quotes will store that variables as a string

```
export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.2"
```

But this doesn't guarantee that `java` command itself will work.

Comment: Yeah, that edit makes echo $JAVA_HOME print out the correct directory but java commands dont work like you said..

Comment: Java has separate installation packages for Linux and Windows. You cannot use Windows installation in Linux, and vice-versa, so you need to install it again within WSL